# PipelineDB, get counts for top K items

Tags: pipelinedb

How to calculate **frequencies of top K values** in the stream?

Let's say we have a stream

```
CREATE STREAM stream (
  value number
);
```

And we inserted ten rows

```
INSERT INTO stream (value) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO stream (value) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO stream (value) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO stream (value) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO stream (value) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO stream (value) VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO stream (value) VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO stream (value) VALUES (5)
INSERT INTO stream (value) VALUES (6)
INSERT INTO stream (value) VALUES (7)
```

How can I get back the **top 2 items and their frequencies**?

```
value | frequency
-----------------
1     | 0.3
2     | 0.2
```

I suppose it should somehow use both Top K and the Count-min Sketch together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fss_agg](http://docs.pipelinedb.com/aggregates.html?highlight=fss#filtered-space-saving-aggregates) for that:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW v AS
  SELECT fss_agg(x, 10) AS top_10_x FROM some_stream
```

This will keep track of the top `10` most frequently occurring values of `x`. The weight given to each value can also be explicitly given:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW v AS
  SELECT fss_agg_weighted(x, 10, y) AS top_10_x FROM some_stream
```

The first version implicitly uses a weight of `1`.

There are various [functions](http://docs.pipelinedb.com/aggregates.html?highlight=fss#filtered-space-saving-aggregates) you can use to read the top-K values and their associated frequencies. For example, the following will return tuples of the form: `(value, frequency)`:

```
SELECT fss_topk(top_10_x) FROM v
```

Comment: How can we incorporate the time window into this? For instance, give me the Top K frequencies given an hour sliding window.